# Session.flash is not cleared after Session.get when using Remix

Tags: session, remix.run

I'm using `Session.flash` do display a flash message to the user, and it seems that the `flash` message persists even after calling `Session.get`. In my case I:

Redirect with a flash message after a successful login:

```
const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
session.flash(FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY, message);
request.headers.get("Cookie");
return redirect(redirectTo, {
    headers: {
        "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
});
```

and in the very next call on the new page I access the session context:

```
export const getContext = async (request: Request) => {
    let user = await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request);
    const isAuthenticated = user !== null;
    const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
    const flash = session.get(FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY) || null;
    return {
        isAuthenticated,
        user: user ?? ANON_USER,
        flash,
    };
};

// ...

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
    const context = await getContext(request);
    return json({
        context,
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the session flash, it also mutates it (removing the flash item). So from your loader, make sure you also return the `set-cookie` header and commit the session.